# how to resolve the issue with menu hover over

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

i work on a website and having trouble with its menu. when i hover over the menu, its sub-menu doesnot appear. so please kindly help me to sort out this issue.

[image]

[Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8iYx.jpg)

http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/

i m using a piece of code to implement jQuery menu

```
var $jnav = jQuery.noConflict();
$jnav(document).ready(function () {
    $jnav('#menu-mainnav li').hover(

    function () {
        $jnav(this).css('background', "url('http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/nav-current-bg.png') no-repeat", 'cursor', "pointer");
        if ($jnav(this).is('#menu-mainnav li:last-child')) {
            $jnav('#menu-mainnav li:last-child').css('background', "url('http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/nav-last-bg.png') no-repeat");
        } else if ($jnav(this).is('.sub-menu li:last-child')) {
            $jnav('.sub-menu li:last-child').css('background', "none scroll #8e4d69");
        }
    }, function () {
        if (!$jnav(this).hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
            $jnav(this).css('background', "none");
        }
        if (!$jnav('#menu-mainnav li:first').hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
            $jnav('#menu-mainnav li:first').css('background', "url('http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/nav-first-bg.png') no-repeat");
        }
    })
    $jnav('#menu-mainnav li ul li').hover(

    function () {
        $jnav(this).css('background-color', "#8e4d69", 'cursor', "pointer");
    }, function () {
        if (!$jnav(this).hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
            $jnav(this).css('background', "#833b5d");
        }
    })
    if (!$jnav('.superfish li:first').hasClass('current-menu-item')) $jnav('.superfish li:first').css('background', "url('http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/nav-first-bg.png') no-repeat");
    $jnav('.superfish li.current-menu-item:last-child').css('background', "url('http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/nav-last-bg.png') no-repeat");
    if (!$jnav('.sub-menu li:first').hasClass('current-menu-item')) $jnav('.sub-menu li:first').css('background', "#833b5d");
    $jnav('.sub-menu li.current-menu-item:last-child').css('background', "#833b5d");

    $jnav('ul.superfish').superfish();
});
```

all the time i have to click over the navigation to see it sub-menu. plz plz plz help me to solve this issue.

thank you.

Comment: Which menu? Can you please post the relevant parts only and not just link to the page in question.

Comment: please take a look i uploaded image of what i want.

Comment: None of the submenus appear here, click or otherwise. You don't really expect people to read that tiny type do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two menu scripts fighting each other for the hover event of your menu (Suckerfish and jNav), remove one of them and your menu should be fixed.

```
var $jnav = jQuery.noConflict();
$jnav(document).ready(function () {
    $jnav('#menu-mainnav li').hover(

    function () {
        $jnav(this).css('background', "url('http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/nav-current-bg.png') no-repeat", 'cursor', "pointer");
        if ($jnav(this).is('#menu-mainnav li:last-child')) {
            $jnav('#menu-mainnav li:last-child').css('background', "url('http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/nav-last-bg.png') no-repeat");
        } else if ($jnav(this).is('.sub-menu li:last-child')) {
            $jnav('.sub-menu li:last-child').css('background', "none scroll #8e4d69");
        }
    }, function () {
        if (!$jnav(this).hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
            $jnav(this).css('background', "none");
        }
        if (!$jnav('#menu-mainnav li:first').hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
            $jnav('#menu-mainnav li:first').css('background', "url('http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/nav-first-bg.png') no-repeat");
        }
    })
    $jnav('#menu-mainnav li ul li').hover(

    function () {
        $jnav(this).css('background-color', "#8e4d69", 'cursor', "pointer");
    }, function () {
        if (!$jnav(this).hasClass('current-menu-item')) {
            $jnav(this).css('background', "#833b5d");
        }
    })
    if (!$jnav('.superfish li:first').hasClass('current-menu-item')) $jnav('.superfish li:first').css('background', "url('http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/nav-first-bg.png') no-repeat");
    $jnav('.superfish li.current-menu-item:last-child').css('background', "url('http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/nav-last-bg.png') no-repeat");
    if (!$jnav('.sub-menu li:first').hasClass('current-menu-item')) $jnav('.sub-menu li:first').css('background', "#833b5d");
    $jnav('.sub-menu li.current-menu-item:last-child').css('background', "#833b5d");
    jQuery('.lightbox').lightBox({
        imageLoading: 'http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/lightbox-ico-loading.gif',
        imageBtnClose: 'http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/lightbox-btn-close.gif',
        imageBtnPrev: 'http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/lightbox-btn-prev.gif',
        imageBtnNext: 'http://www.mulberrydesignerkitchens.com/wp-content/themes/MBK/images/lightbox-btn-next.gif'
    });
    $jnav('#logo').hover(function () {
        $jnav(this).css('opacity', '0.8');
    }, function () {
        $jnav(this).css('opacity', '1');
    });
    $jnav('#homepage-images h4').css('display', 'none');
    $jnav('ul.superfish').superfish({
        hoverClass: 'nav#primary-menu a'
    });
});
```

For suckerfish to work all you need is:

```
<script> 

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('ul.sf-menu').superfish(); 
    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: well if i just remove anyone of them. my all style will gone. can u please help me how can i keep the same style and its hover over also.

Comment: @Muzammil remove that JS block and just use the classes provided by suckerfish and use CSS to style your menu. From what i can tell you're using javascript to style your menu when you can easily style it with simple CSS. Suckerfish provides a hoverClass that you can use to style the hover event on your menu items (to add the slanted image). `hoverClass: 'sfHover'`

Comment: Ilich okay.. thank you very much. let me try but if you can give me some code. it will be very helpfull to understand.

Comment: @Muzammil tough order you have there chief :P ..specially at lunch time... but here is a fiddle to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/pjSE4/ ... start replacing all those styles you're adding with javascript with simple CSS.

Comment: Ilich - Thank you very much. finaly its done. thank you again

Comment: @Muzammil glad i could help. Don't forget to nick the answer as correct if it helped you to clear your issue.

Comment: yes i already tick the answer.. and it was really helpfull for me. thanks alot again.